# Comparing multidimensional lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two multidimensional lists `J,Cond`. For every `True` element of `Cond[0]`, I want the corresponding element in `J[0]` to be zero. I present the current and expected output.

```
J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
Cond=[[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]]

for i in range(0,len(J[0])):
    if(Cond[0][i]==True):
        J[0][i]==0
print(J)
```

The current output is

```
[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: `==` is used for comparison. To assign a value, use `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `J[0][i] = 0` instead of `J[0][i] == 0`.
Assignment is done by a single equal sign, while checking for equality is done by double equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

You have an operator error in the if condition. Here is the code for the same

```
J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
Cond=[[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]]

for i in range(0,len(J[0])):
    if(Cond[0][i] == True):
        J[0][i] = 0 
print(J)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code :

1. J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
2. Cond=[[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]]
3. 
4. for i in range(0,len(J[0])):
5. ```
   if(Cond[0][i]==True):
   ```
6. ```
       J[0][i]==0
   ```
7. print(J)

In line no.6 your statement : J[0][i]==0, here, the == operator is used for checking equality of the statement and returns a boolean value. So, your J[0][i] is only being compared with integer 0 and is not being assigned any value.
Assignment operator is =.
The correct statement for assignment would be : J[0][i]=0. After this, the J[0][i] would be assigned value as integer 0.
You only need to replace this line and you will get the required output.
So the corrected code would look like this :

1. J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
2. Cond=[[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]]
3. 
4. for i in range(0,len(J[0])):
5. ```
   if(Cond[0][i]==True):
   ```
6. ```
       J[0][i]=0
   ```
7. print(J)

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip to pair up the lines and zip again to pair up the items of each line:

```
J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
Cond=[[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]]

J = [ [(n,0)[c] for n,c in zip(rJ,rC)] for rJ,rC in zip(J,Cond) ]

print(J)

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```